# Captive portal with voucher support

Tags: captive-portal, wifi

Can someone recommend an open source captive portal that can run on a Linux machine(not wifi routers) with voucher support?

I know wifidog can be configured to use username and password authentication but I just want a key that is valid for say 1 hour which can be used to access Internet. After that hour, the user will have to get another voucher to continue using internet. Is this possible with wifidog?

I don't want to use pfsense(or other distro based solutions) as I already have a Linux machine doing other stuff and would like to install captive portal on it.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as per the documentation:

Paid tokens

You buy access for a day or an hour using a credit card. Examples: Most typical commercial hotspot operators.

http://dev.wifidog.org/wiki/WirelessCommunityModels

Comment: Thanks Elbert. I tried to setup Wifidog for weeks and I got the gateway to work properly but the auth server just wouldn't work.

I also tried authpuppy but no luck with that either.

In the end I had to use pfsense and it was a 15 minute to get it up and running!